# Proving that no finite automaton can recognize a Dyck language

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata

I was reading up on finite automata and I came across an interesting fact near the end of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton).

> The classic example of a simply described language that no DFA can
>   recognize is bracket or Dyck language, i.e., the language that
>   consists of properly paired brackets such as word "(()())".
>   Intuitively, no DFA can recognize the Dyck language because DFAs are
>   not capable of counting: [...]

Although it is very intuitive the argument they gave, I was wondering if there were a formal proof I could read for this, or if simple enough, reconstruct.

I tried Googling around for a proof, but I think I am missing some sort of a keyword in my search because nothing useful is coming up, it this proof trivial or intuitive enough that no papers have been published on it?

Comment: Suitable keywords for you: Pumping Lemma, Myhill-Nerode theorem. The proof is really easy.
Check out also: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a Dyck language $L$ with $k$ types of parentheses, one of them $()$. If $L$ were regular then $L \cap (^*)^*$ would be regular, but this is just the well-known non-regular language $a^nb^n$ (with $a,b$ replaced by $(,)$).

There are many ways to prove that $L' = \{a^nb^n : n \geq 0\}$ isn't regular. Here is one. Suppose that $A$ is a DFA recognizing $L'$, with states $Q$, initial state $q_0$, accepting states $F$, and transition function $\delta$. Let $q(i) = \delta(q_0,a^i)$. If $i < j$ then $q(i) \neq q(j)$, since otherwise $\delta(q_0,a^ib^i) = \delta(q_0,a^jb_i)$ although the former is in $F$ while the latter isn't. This implies the absurd conclusion that $Q$ must be infinite.